# How can I use Rx with C# await calls to retrieve JSON data from web

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient, system.reactive

I have a method that calls an API with `HttpClient` and build a list of Customers as `IEnumerable<Customer>`. The way this API works is that it will return only 100 customers at a time, and will provide another link in the JSON content to fetch again the next 100.

How can I structure this code to iteratively fetch the records until all are fetched and build a large `IEnumerable<Customer>` and return from this method. I'm looking for the solution with Rx.

```
Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetCustomers(string url)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  
  // TODO: Deserialize responseBody and build a new IEnumerable<Customer>
}

Json:

{
    nextRecords: '\customers\123'
    customers: [
        {
            name: 'John Doe'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mary Doe'
        }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide enough code to call the API, specify the page number (i.e. which 100 customers to get), and then build the customers? Also, how do we know when you have all of the records? It would then be trivial to create an Rx method to build the whole lot.

Comment: (1) The URI is like ```\customers\```. The customers that returned from the server is set to 100. You can't change it from the client. (2) The only way to know that there are no more records is by looking at the ```nextRecords``` field. That value will be empty if there are no more records.

Comment: How does the server distinguish between two consecutive client calls and two parallel client calls? i.e. two calls trying to get the first 100 records each and two calls trying to get the the first and second 100 records?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're calling the URL with the `nextRecords` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the signature from `Task<IEnumerable<Customer>>` to `IObservable<Customer>` to make it more Rx-like.

You need to define the `Func<JObject, IObservable<Customer>> createCustomers` function.

Try having a go at this:

```
IObservable<Customer> GetCustomers(string url)
{
    Func<JObject, IObservable<Customer>> createCustomers = jo => { ... };
    return Observable.Create<Customer>(o =>
    {
        var final_url = url + "\\customers";
        return
            Observable
                .While(
                    () => final_url != url,
                    Observable
                        .Using(
                            () => new HttpClient(),
                            client =>
                                from x in Observable.FromAsync(() => client.GetAsync(final_url))
                                from y in Observable.Start(() =>
                                {
                                    x.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                                    return x;
                                })
                                from z in Observable.FromAsync(() => y.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
                                from w in Observable.Start(() =>
                                {
                                    var j = JObject.Parse(z);
                                    final_url = url + j.Property("nextRecords").Value;
                                    return createCustomers(j);
                                })
                                from v in w
                                select v))
                .Subscribe(o);
    });
}
```